Aws Amplify redirect social media bot to ec2(rendertron)
I have one ec2 instance with rendertron docker container running on https://example.com.
my frontend code is deploy on aws amplify, now how i can redirect bot to ec2 and user to /index.html based on user agent ?
what will be the changes required in amplify.yml ??
I want bot redirect to ec2 and normal user serve with index.html
